# reload a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, url, uiwebview, webview, nsurlrequest

I'm using a UIWebView like that in the viewDidLoad:

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 88, 320, 400)]; //  init and create the UIWebView
    webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
    [webView  setDelegate:self];//set the web view delegates for the web view to be itself
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]];//Create a URL object & Set the URL to go to for your UIWebView
    [webView loadRequest:requestObject];//load the URL into the web view.
    [self.view addSubview:webView];//add the web view to the content view
    [webView release], webView = nil;
```

When I try to change the page, I try that **BUT** it doesn't working :

```
[webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"]]];
[webView reload];
```

The code that's just above is in the action of a TabBar button.

**EDIT :
 When I comment

```
[webView release], webView = nil;
```

I can see the apple website but not facebook when I push the button! The screen is refreshing in the apple website and not facebook...**

Hundred of thanks to help ;-)

Comment: You don't need to do [webView reload]; after [webView loadRequest:..];.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've released and set your webView to nil.  So the object no longer exists.  You are calling loadRequest and reload on a nil object which will do nothing.

Assuming you have webView as an instance variable in your class, remove the line

```
[webView release], webView = nil;
```

and instead put that in your dealloc method otherwise when you call

```
[webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"]]];
```

then you will be calling it on a nil object which will do nothing.

Comment: OK, it's working perfectly now ! I have delete the two lines and put yours and all is all right, THANKS !!!!

Comment: @clement Don't forget you will still need to call release on the webView otherwise you will leak memory.  Put it in your dealloc method

Comment: Yes thanks, I've put "[webView release]" in the dealloc method

Answer (score 2):

Where did you try this code ?

```
[webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"]]];
[webView reload];
```

You already released webview and make it Nil. So it will not work if you did it after it loads  www.apple.com.

```
[webView release], webView = nil;
```

Remove above two lines once and then try. It should work. 
Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

The potential problem I see is that you are setting the webView value to nil after adding it as subview, but before doing the reload:

```
 [webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"]]];
 [webView reload];
```

here `webView` is nil... the object still exists (because it is embedded in a view), but the variable does not point to it anymore, so messages are simply ignored.

Answer (score 1):

no need of reload

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
     [webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"]]];
}
```

this may help..!!

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code, I guess that the your `webView` is declared as `@property` in the header file. You release this object after the Apple site is loaded. I think that's the reason why it doesn't load the facebook website.

The `[webView release];` should be placed within the `- (void) dealloc` method only.

Please let me know if it works!